# postgrest `stack test` gives: FATAL: database "test/create_test_db "postgres://postgres:pwd@database-host" tes" does not exist

Tags: postgrest

`stack test` gives error:

```
postgrest> test (suite: spec)

psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-f" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "test/fixtures/database.sql" ignored
psql: FATAL:  database "test/create_test_db "postgres://postgres:pwd@database-host" tes" does not exist
spec.exe: readCreateProcess: psql "--set" "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" "test/create_test_db \"postgres://postgres:pwd@database-host\" test_db" "Trader" "-f" "test/fixtures/database.sql" (exit 2): failed

postgrest> Test suite spec failed
Test suite failure for package postgrest-6.0.2
    spec:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```

I'm on Windows10, and have set system environment variable POSTGREST_TEST_CONNECTION:

```
test/create_test_db "postgres://postgres:pwd@database-host" test_db
```

`psql` in the terminal gives

```
psql (11.5)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

Trader=#
```